# How to make a changeset pushed for code review dependent on newer changeset pushed for different code review afterwards

Tags: git, gerrit

I wonder if it is possible to make an already pushed gerrit code review dependent on a pushed later different one, is there something like a `Depends-On: <ChangeId>` commit message footer?

If not, how would it be possible with `git` itself to rebase CR1 on CR2 without too much hassle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependencies in Gerrit are normal parent-child git relationships. You can create a dependency by rebasing one code review patch set onto another one, like this (you can find the correct references from the patch set [download](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-review-ui.html#download) menu):

```
git fetch ssh://your_repo/your_project refs/changes/n/changenum1/patchset:CR1
git fetch ssh://your_repo/your_project refs/changes/n/changenum2/patchset:CR2
git checkout CR1
git rebase CR2
```

Now you can publish your rebased CR1 as usual. You should see a dependency to CR2 for the updated patch set.